# New subsection definition redefines original subsection numbering

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I created new section (i.e., "Workpackage") and subsection (i.e., "Task") headings using `titlesec` package. The definitions for both headings are as follows.

```
% Workpackage section
\titleclass{\WP}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\WP}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{Work Package \theWP :\,}
\titlespacing*{\WP}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcounter{WP}
\renewcommand\theWP{\arabic{WP}}

% Task subsection
\newcounter{Taskr}
\renewcommand\theTaskr{\theWP.\arabic{Taskr}}
\titleclass{\Taskr}{straight}[\WP]
\titleformat{\Taskr}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{}{0em}{Task \theTaskr :\,}
\titlespacing*{\Taskr}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\numberwithin{Taskr}{WP}
```

However, when I compiled the document the ordinary subsection headings are without heading numbers, e.g.:

```
1. Section
Subsection
Subsection
2. Section
Subsection
Workpackage 1
Task 1.1
```

instead of

```
1. Section
1.1 Subsection
1.2 Subsection
2. Section
2.2 Subsection
Workpackage 1
Task 1.1
```

Any how to modify my definitions? The MWE is pasted below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Workpackage section
\titleclass{\WP}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\WP}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{Work Package \theWP :\,}
\titlespacing*{\WP}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcounter{WP}
\renewcommand\theWP{\arabic{WP}}

% Task subsection
\newcounter{Taskr}
\renewcommand\theTaskr{\theWP.\arabic{Taskr}}
\titleclass{\Taskr}{straight}[\WP]
\titleformat{\Taskr}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{}{0em}{Task \theTaskr :\,}
\titlespacing*{\Taskr}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\numberwithin{Taskr}{WP}

% Don't want to include WP and Tasks into bookmarks and TOC
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@WP{6}
  \def\toclevel@Taskr{5}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem definition}

\WP{Project management}
\Taskr{Project advisory board}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\titleclass` command is defined to insert a new level *between* the existing levels (with lower levels pushed down), not as an alternative to an existing level. It is however not very difficult to create alternative levels manually (without `titlesec` and the associated numbering behaviour), you just have to pay attention to spacing issues (note: the example below undoubtedly has remaining issues).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{WP}
\newcounter{Taskr}
\newcommand{\WP}[1]{%
\stepcounter{WP}%
\setcounter{Taskr}{0}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries%
\bigbreak\noindent Work Package \theWP :\,#1}\par\noindent\ignorespaces%
}

\newcommand{\Taskr}[1]{%
\stepcounter{Taskr}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape%
\par\noindent Task \theWP .\theTaskr :\,#1}\par\noindent\ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem definition}

\WP{Project management}
This WP consists of two tasks.
\Taskr{Project advisory board}
Advise on the project.

\Taskr{Budget allocation}

\WP{Prototype}
\Taskr{Research existing solutions}

\subsection{Further considerations}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still struggling with spacing. Any idea?

Comment: Which changes do you want to make to the current spacing?